# Read in the data with csv.reader() and store it in a list of lists called 'data'

Tags: python, csv

This is what I have to do:

Read in the data with `csv.reader()` and store it in a list of lists called `data`. This is a TSV file, and `csv.reader()` needs to be told how to handle it.

This is what I wrote:

```
import csv
with open('orders.tsv') as f:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')]
```

And the error basically says it can't find the file, what am I missing here?

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-08bb0845fb8f> in <module>()
      1 import csv
----> 2 with open('orders.tsv') as f:
      3     data = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')]

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'orders.tsv'
```

**FIXED**

import csv
 with open('../data/orders.tsv') as f:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')]

Comment: Try `print(open('orders.tsv').read()[:100])` before proceeding to CSV parsing.  It should print out the first 100 characters from `orders.tsv`.  If it fails, then the file path is wrong.

Comment: thanks i figured it out!

Answer (score 3):

The error is just as it describes, the program will look for the file in the working directory, and if it can't find it, error. To see what your current working directory is, you can use:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```

Comment: nvm i figured it out, thanks.

Comment: @YoungBobsta: Can you post your answer so that others in the same situation, can know what to do?